# After adding these many dependencies project not responding

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-mvvm, kodein

Build.gradle(Module:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.protocol.mvvmshoppinglist'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.protocol.mvvmshoppinglist"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    def room_version = "2.2.1"
    def kodein_version = "6.4.0"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"

    // Room and Architectural Components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"

    // New Material Design
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    // Kodein
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:$kodein_version"
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android-x:$kodein_version"
}
```

I added the dependencies like, Room and Architectural components, Coroutines, New Material Design, ViewModel and Kodein, after adding these project gives the error:
Caused by:

> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the BOM library.

The Compose Bill of Materials (BOM) lets you manage all of your Compose library versions by specifying only the BOM’s version.

For More info visit below url

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom